# The right number of Servlets

Tags: android, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web application composed by one servlet, one jsp website and an Android client.
I would like to permit the Servlet to comunicate with jsp and Android via JSON object.
Is it possible or should I make two Servlet, one for Android and one for jsp?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can! In Android you can convert easily that json to an object and in jsp you could have the object in a session variable.

Comment: Thanks! You would use one Servlet or two?

Comment: I would use 2, so you can separate traffic and distinguish clearly client connections.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll take your advice!